# How do you use this @ in C#?

Tags: c#

```
simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav");
```

Why and what is the @ for?

Comment: called 'verbatim strings': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a literal string. Instead of having to escape the "\" by putting two of them "\" the compiler interprets the string "as is".

Say you wanted to print out the following text to the screen: `"Hello \t world"`.

If you were to just do `Console.WriteLine("Hello \t world")`, then your output would be:

```
Hello    world
```

notice the tab. That's because \t is interperted as a tab. If you use the literal though, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"Hello \t world")
```

then your output would be:

```
"Hello \t world"
```

Comment: And you embed double-quotes in the string by doubling them:  `@"1\2""3"` becomes `1\2"3`.

Answer (score 2):

The @ sign before a string means to treat the backslash as a normal character rather than the start of a special character (such as newline).

Answer (score 2):

It identifies a [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It allows you to have the special character `\` in the string without escaping it.

Comment: "This is a *regular* string literal with no @" -- it (@) identifies a *verbatim* string-literal. Good inclusion of a link though.

Answer (score 2):

It is a verbatim string. A verbatim string allows you to include special characters like \, " etc. without using the escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`"c:\\my\\file.txt"` could be done as `@"c:\my\file.txt"`

This means your \n and \t or whatever it is will also not be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Another usage of `@` is that you can put it in front of a keyword, if you want to use a keyword as a variable name (even if it's not a good idea). Example:

```
public int @object = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining the @ symbol prior to the assigning a string value will prevent the need for doubling the backslash (\) in C#. The at symbol (@) simply ignores escape characters.